# Is there a vector affine transformation tool in QGIS2?

Tags: vector, qgis-2, coordinate-system, affine-transformation

In QGIS 1.8, I can transform my point layer with the plugin "Affine transformation". So, this plugin don't exist in QGIS 2.0.

Do you know a method to simply translate (i.e : X -> X+30000) in QGIS 2 ? It's possible in QGIS or I must use ogr2ogr, QGIS 1.8 or openjump ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ogr2ogr` with SpatiaLite support (GDAL version >= 1.10):

```
ogr2ogr points_shifted.shp points.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ShiftCoords(geometry,30000,0) FROM points"
```

Answer (score 3):

`Affine Transformations` is included now in the plugin repository.

`Vector Bender` has a similar georeference-like approach, but is still only experimental.